# Matplotlib ticks overlapping

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

If I change the matplotlib font size, e.g. `mpl.rc( 'font', size=20 )`, my ticks overlap with one another. Is there any workaround? I don't want to define ticks myself, neither to rotate them, I guess mpl should be able to do it itself.

Comment: The tick marks overlap, or the tick mark _labels_ overlap?  Can you post an image?

Answer (score 1):

If the font is to big you'll need to give some more space to the text. You can do it by rotating the labels:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

, or change the font size of the labels:

```
for tick in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
     tick.label.set_fontsize(14)
```

Comment: @fmonegaglia In that case you'll either need to reduce the font size or reduce the number of tick labels. I've edited the answer.

Comment: But the point is that this is very dependent from the output. Shouldn'y mpl be able to understand how many ticks to put once it knows their font?

Comment: @fmonegaglia mpl does not do that automatically because font and text in general follow different rules from the typical marker positioning (axis values). You'll be able to test this just by resizing the window. Notice how the axis ticks are redraw to a new scale but the text remains the same size. You'll need to build your own handler if you want the text to be managed.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from @armatia's method. Hidden some xtickslabel was also an solution.
Code like this:

```
for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[::2]:
    label.set_visible(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to rotate labels like in @armatita's answer, but don't have a reference to the `plt` object (like all examples assume), you can do this with your reference to the axis object:

```py
axis.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)
```